# Query to count table from all databases on server with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to do a COUNT from CM.SITES where Availability is equal to 1 (INT).

I have modified a query I found online, however I am running into issues adding the WHERE clause.

This is what I have so far, it returns the count of all records in CM.SITES

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF OBJECT_ID (N'tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
   DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp
(
      [COUNT] INT
    , DB VARCHAR(50)
)

DECLARE @TableName NVARCHAR(50) 
SELECT @TableName = 'cm.sites'

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = STUFF((
    SELECT CHAR(13) + 'SELECT ''' + name + ''', COUNT(1) FROM [' + name + '].' + @TableName
    FROM sys.databases 
    WHERE OBJECT_ID(name + '.' + @TableName) IS NOT NULL and @TableName + '.' + 'Availability' is not null
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')

INSERT INTO #temp (DB, [COUNT])              
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL

SELECT * 
FROM #temp t
```

This works since it is looking for Availability IS NOT NULL, however when I try to change this to =1, I get the error

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'cm.sites.Availability' to data type int.

I tried to add a Cast to the SELECT line but couldn't figure it out.

Does anyone know what I am missing here?

I need this query to run and count for each DB on the server.

Comment: Are you getting the error on this line: EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to change:

```
'Availability' is not null
```

to:

```
'Availability' =1
```

What you really should have is:

```
'Availability is not null'
```

Which easily becomes:

```
'Availability = 1'
```

Always confusing where to place quotes with dynamic SQL!

Comment: That was my initial thought as well, but look again: this is a part of the query that generates the dynamic sql...

Comment: Are you getting the error on this line: EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL ?

Comment: Are you asking me or the OP?

Comment: Hi, I changed 'Availability' =1 to 'Availability = 1', I'm getting Msg 4145, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'FOR'.

Answer (score 0):

Add a where clause to the dynamic query.  Before the `FROM sys.databases` add this:

```
+ ' Where Availability = 1'
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that Availability is a nvarchar column and you are trying to compare it to an integer. SQL is trying to convert the Availability column to an integer and failing.

Instead use Availability = '1' so that no type conversion will take place. Note that this will not match '0001','01',etc... just '1'.